# How to understand sender and receiver in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminology

I find it hard to understand the actual meaning of sender and receiver in Ruby. What do they mean in general? So far I simply understand them as the method call and the one that takes its return value. However, I know my understanding is far from enough. Can anyone give me an specific explanation of sender and receiver in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A core concept in Object Orientation is messaging and early conceptualization borrowed much from the Actor Model of computation.  Alan Kay, the guy who coined the term Object Oriented and invented one of the first OO languages SmallTalk, has [voiced regret at using a term which put the focus on objects instead of on messages, which he considered the stronger idea](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKayOnMessaging).

When talking about a message, there's a natural "sender" and "receiver" of the message.  The sender is the object which invokes a method, the receiver is the object whose method is invoked.  In Ruby, if one calls a method without explicitly naming an object, that sends the method name and its args as a message to the default receiver `self`.

In OO, "making a call", "invoking a method", and "sending a message" are equivalent concepts. Similarly "being called", "having one's method invoked", and "receiving a message" are equivalent.

Comment: Another point is that the actual sender is not talked about much. But if we say the results come back to the sender, that sender may be something in (the interpreter or the syntax graph of) that line of code. E.g., in 'a.b.c(d)' the sender to b is some temporary object which stands ready to receive b's results and then send those results on in another message to a. So, I haven't heard much about the sender.

Answer (score 5):

When you write a Ruby program and you tell a string to reverse itself, you are the sender and the string object is the receiver. For example,

```
"this is a string".reverse
"this is a string".send(:reverse) # equivalent
```

What you, as a coder, are doing is sending a message :reverse to that string object, which is the receiver of that message, and the output will be

```
=> "gnirts a si siht"
```

which is the return value.

You can query whether an object can handle the message you want to send:

```
"this is a string".respond_to?(:reverse)
=> true
Hash.new.respond_to?(:reverse)
=> false
```

That's the simplest example entirely from playing in irb. When you write complex programs that might interact with other APIs, like Twitter (to take a common example), then you would instantiate a client object that you can send message to like "get all tweets containing this hashtag."

Comment: @AlanFung-Schwartz - thank you for your answer. have a question: is the reciever the String class, or the instance of the class which is: "this is a string" object?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon The receiver is the instance of the String class, calling a method on the instance causes a lookup of the method defined in the String class object.

Answer (score 3):

## Simple Explanation with Picture

```
a = "test123"

a.reverse # => '321tset'
```

Look closely at the colours**.

[image: Summary with a diagram]

**Example of Usage:**

Someone might say:

> The `reverse` method is "called" on `a`.

What does it mean: let's break it down:

### What is the message?

- "reverse" is the **message**. you can think of messages as basically methods.

### What is the receiver?

- The string `a` is the **receiver** of the message.

### What is the sender?

- And the sender is the object where all of this is called. in this case, the object is `self`, which is `main`.

** (my condolences if you are unable to see the colours. Notice carefully: black vs blue vs red.):

#### Prologue: "Inovking" Methods

I very much dislike the use of expressions e.g. "invoking methods on on objects". This might be confusing  ¯\*(ツ)*/¯  , especially if English is not your native language. What does it mean?

`a.reverse`

the "reverse" method is "invoked" upon the `a` object.

Comment: This is the best answer so far

Answer (score 1):

These terms are coming from the fundamental concepts of object orientation as taught by Smalltalk.
Remember: everything is an object. The only way that objects can interact is through sending each other messages.

The convenient way of saying `obj.do_somthing` is in fact the current `self` sending a message "hey obj, please do_something". The return value of obj's do_something method can be seen as the answer to that message.

```
class A
  def foo(obj)
    obj.send(:object_id) 
  end
end
a = A.new
b = Object.new
a.foo(b)
=> 4232
```

In this example `a` is the "sender" and `b` is the "receiver".

Comment: Kind of a bad example, since the object stored in `a` is the receiver in the outside invocation (`a.foo(b)`), and the object stored in `b` is the receiver inside `A#foo` (i.e. it is `obj` in `obj.send(:object_id)`).

Comment: In other words, a and obj are the receivers in lines 8 and 3. In this code, as line 3 is executed, a is the sender. Actually also, in lines 6 and 7, a and b are the receivers of the '=' method, and A and Object are the receivers of the 'new' method.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell: There is no `=` method in Ruby. Local variable assignment is *not* a message send (and thus *not* object-oriented!!!), it doesn't even make sense to talk about "sender" and "receiver" if you don't have a message. However, if assignment *were* implemented as a message send, then the receiver would be the current lexical scope and `a` and `b` would be the *arguments* to the message send. After all, they don't exist before they are assigned so how would you send them a message? IOW: `foo = 42` would be equivalent to something like `binding.local_variable_set(:foo, 42)`.

Comment: That's how it works in Ioke and Seph, for example. `foo = 42` is just syntax sugar for `=(foo, 42)`, i.e. send the message `=` with the (unevaluated!) arguments `foo` and `42` to the default receiver, which is *not* `self` but rather the current evaluation context. Likewise, in Newspeak, which doesn't have variables, `foo ::= 42` is syntax sugar for "create a pair of getter and setter methods `foo` on the current lexical scope object and set the backing store to `42`".

Comment: @JörgWMittag, of course you're right about Ruby local assignment (my thinking was fuzzy), and thanks for the info on [Ioke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioke_%28programming_language%29) (drawn from Io) and [Seph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seph_%28programming_language%29) (both designed by Ola Bini), and [Newspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak_%28programming_language%29), partly inspired by the venerated [Self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: So for Ruby, not everything is an object, and we can't properly say, as often we do, that objects send and receive messages (to each other). Instead, we should say that objects receive messages only, and it's code which sends them. Somehow this reminds me, which I learned from @dbenhur's answer, of Alan Kay later voicing regret over his emphasizing objects, rather than messages. Perhaps our tendency to anthropomorphize objects causes this persistent misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you confused "caller" for "sender". I don't know what "sender" is in this context.

A method can have an embedded method:

```
def foo argument
  object.bar(argument)
end
```

In the case above, `foo` is the caller of `bar`. `object` is the receiver of `bar`.

Comment: `foo` is not the sender of `bar` above. `foo` is a method of an object, that object is the sender. It sends message `:bar` to receiver `object` while executing its method `foo` after receiving message `:foo, argument` from somewhere.

Comment: Unlike "caller" and "receiver", "sender" doesn't seem to be a well-defined concept in Ruby. FWIW though, the [sender gem](https://github.com/asher-/sender#readme) considers the "sender" to be the object that was `self` in whatever block of code called the method. But sawa is correct -- `foo` is the *caller*.