# Could you explain sender and receiver in OOP and give examples?

Tags: oop, object, methods, receiver, sender

I have read [this similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592268/how-to-understand-sender-and-receiver-in-ruby) but I still don't understand at all, therefore I hope you guys can help me to understand the general meaning and give more examples of it.

Comment: Which programming language do you want the examples to be in?

Comment: Hmm....it could be one of them like Ruby, PHP or Java. Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand in the duplicate that makes it necessary to ask the same question all over again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand sender and receiver in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592268/how-to-understand-sender-and-receiver-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message in this context is basically "calling a ,method/accessing a property", as the post you mentioned said.

Let's see an example in Java:

```
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.doStuff(); // *
    }
}

class Foo {
    public void doStuff() {}
}
```

In the line marked by the asterisk, a method call is done. I.e. You are sending a message. The "sender" of the message is where you are calling the method i.e. `MyClass`. The "receiver" is the object on which you call the method i.e. an instance of `Foo`. And the message itself is the method called i.e. `doStuff`.

In languages where properties exist, like in Swift and C sharp, accessing properties also counts as sending a message.